# Copying layers between WebMaps on ArcGIS Onlinr?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Background:

I am/have created a "Master" WebMap and topic specific WebMaps on ArcGIS Online that will be used in creating multiple Web AppBuilder apps.

The Master WebMap has multiple (40+) external web services as well as my own services created in ArcMap.

The Issue:

I am looking to create new WebMaps with my own services including a range of external services from the Master WebMap to these new WebMaps. I do not want to re-add the layers again for each new WebMap as I have created custom scales/symbology/popups that I would not like to redo!

From what I can see there is no information on this online. Has anyone any information if this is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the webmaps by using the [ArcGIS Online Assistant](https://ago-assistant.esri.com/). Choose `I want to.. > Copy Content > My Account` and then drag a webmap from the Root or a folder (from the left) to the right panel into the `Drop items to copy to this folder` area.

Refresh My Content and you should be able to see the newly copied webmap. It will have the same name, but the URL will be different (ie the ItemID is different). You can rename the copied webmap and keep editing it.

More AGOL tools and handy apps here at [ago-admin-wiki](https://github.com/Esri/ago-admin-wiki/wiki/Tools)

Comment: Thank you @Alex for that info and the link to the admin wiki site. I am aware of the ArcGIS Online Administrator. It is very useful. I also noticed that this has the ability of viewing an items JSON. I thought this would give be a way of seeing what data is in which WebMap and it does, **BUT** the functionality to copy across snippets to another webmap and update the JSON is in development and **breaks** the updated webmap! I was hoping there was a way of copying the layers instead of the webmap as in the future this would be faster/easier for me.

Comment: Ah, OK, so you have tried creating a copy of the web map without JSON (just drag-drop items)? What is the particular problem with that approach?

Comment: The main problem is that I have had to create 8 local services for a particular county in Ireland (Archaeology-Species). These are in a webmap with 40+ external services with pop-ups, symbology, etc. configured. The project progressed and looking to use 8 new services that encompass data for all of Ireland. I tried to simply create a new webmap and update the service urls in ArcGIS Assistant but since there are more/different layers in these services all the pop-ups for both the 8 local and 40+ external services are messed up. e.g. popup for layer 2 = layer 1, layer 3 = layer 2, etc (part 1/2)

Comment: I now have 2 test webmaps one with the 8 All Ireland services and one with the 40+ external services (copy of original but removed local services). I merge of the 2 webmaps would be ideal as re-doing these pop-ups is a nightmare. If there was a way of having pop-ups on by default this would definitely suffice. Thanks (part 2/2)